# android MediaCodec encoding h.264 can only encoding one frame

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

I configure the MediaCodec with this

```
mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE,
            width, height);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitrate); // 
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, framerate); // frame rate
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, iFramerate); 
    mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null,
            MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    mediaCodec.start();
```

and send the data with 
Called from Camera.onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)

```
try {
        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
            inputBuffer.clear();
            if (inputBuffer.capacity() < input.length) {
                byte[] temp = new byte[input.length];
                System.arraycopy(input, 0, temp, 0, temp.length);
                inputBuffer.put(temp);
            } else {
                inputBuffer.put(input);
            }
            mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length,
                    0, 0);
        }

        MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo,
                0);

        while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
```

The input(byte[]) comes from the camera preview. And I follow the code in API-DOC .
But when i running this code, i can only get one frame succeed.
Which means outputBufferIndex get >=0 only one time whatever how long it's running.
where is the problem?

Comment: You can find some information and examples at bigflake (http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) and in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).

Comment: yes.. I found something very usefull in bigflake.com/mediacodec. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, could you explain what did you find from bigflake.com/mediacodec @Denzww ?

Answer (score 4):

for some encoders,when you encode video frames you should add timestamp.

> mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length,0, 0);

for some encoders this func should change to:

> mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0,
>   input.length,(long)ptsUsec, 0);

note:"ptsUsec" should be different every time.you can creat is like this:
long ptsUsec = (long) generateIndex * 1000000 / VideoConfig.VIDEO_FPS;
(English is poor...)